# Changing innerHTML in javascript removes link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block of text that I want to keep hidden until the user asks to view it. This is my HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('01');">
       <div id="title01">
            Show details
       </div>
    </a>
    <div id="hide01" class="details">
        Description:
    </div>
```

Now, the block hiding and showing works just fine, but when I change the innerHTML on the div `title01`, it no longer remains a link.

Here's my JS:

```
    var div = document.getElementById('hide'+div_id);
    var title = document.getElementById('title'+div_id);

    if (div.style.display === 'block')
    {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        div.style.display = 'block';    
        title.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    }
```

Since I am changing the `innerHTML` on the div with id `title01` only, I fail to understand why it doesn't remain a link. And what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/SwyRP/ (in Chrome). Although I don't think that it is valid to have a `div` inside an `a` (block element inside inline element). Try with a `span` instead, some browsers might correct this and move the `div` outside the `a` element.

Comment: Nice link. That's gonna be useful. I'm surprised though, because it's not working in chrome. It changes the text as I expect, but the new text no longer remains a link. I'll try it with `span` as well.

Comment: Checked in IE 9 as well, and the text doesn't remain a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it by removing the `<div>` entirely and giving the `<a>` tag the id.

So, my new HTML looks like:

```
<a id = "title01" href="javascript:toggleDisplay('01');">
       Show details
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery text function to change content

```
 $('#title01').text("data to display");
```

Comment: I'd rather not use jQuery for a task this tiny.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the problem is the div inside an a.  That is illegal, and the behavior will be odd.  If you have to have block level markup inside an a, use spans set to display:block.